# React Native: which firebase storage npm package to use?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

A learner in React native and Firebase.

Here is my code to intialize firebase storage and fetch url for a storage path:

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


  const storage = firebase.storage();

  let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('photos/flower.png');
  console.log(imageRef);
```

I expect `imageRef` to be containing url for the Firebase storage's image file.

But I get the error:

> ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_firebase.firebase.storage')

I feel, the error is due to wrong package name import.

Could someone guide me on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect imageRef to be containing url for the Firebase storage's image file.

Firstly, you should follow the [example](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage#creating-a-reference) in the documentation.

The [core documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/app/usage) also says:

> Unlike the Firebase Web SDK, there is no need to manually call the initializeApp method with your project credentials.

So you shouldn't have to call initializeApp at all if you set things up correctly.

[ref()](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/storage#ref) returns a [Reference](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/storage/reference) type object, which is just a pointer to the file.  If you want an HTTPS type URL to download the content of that file, you will need to use its [getDownloadURL](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/storage/reference#getDownloadURL) method to get that.

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

let imageRef = storage().ref('photos/flower.png');
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    console.log(url);
})
```

Comment: Hi @Doug, even after as you suggested. Error stills remain the same: 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.firebase.storage')'

Could you please once check, if my import is correct ? Which all imports are needed here ?

Comment: You should follow the example in the documentation.  https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage#creating-a-reference

Comment: Thank you @Doug.
Following the link was helpful.